# How to work this map operator in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, dictionary

I get confused about the map operator in regexp.

My script

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my @ar = map{~s/da//g} <DATA>;
print "@ar\n";

__DATA__
da
```

In this program execute on version 5.16.2 or 5.14.2 gives output is `4294967294` but in that program run on the version 5.18.2 gives output is `18446744073709551614`.

I'm in creasing the data value like

```
__DATA__
da
da da 
da da da da
da da da da da
```

This output in version 5.18.2

```
18446744073709551614 18446744073709551613 18446744073709551611 18446744073709551610
```

Output in version 5.16.2 or 5.14.2

```
4294967294 4294967293 4294967291 4294967290
```

That the last number was decrease by the input data matches occurrence.

Actually I'm not trying this for any problem. I expect

**1)** what is meaning of the digit in outputs?

**2)** why the output change in each version (v5.18.2 , v5.16.2)?

Comment: Who vote down add comment :)

Comment: BTW map is not an operator but function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

choroba has already given the answer. I came up with this visualization to help show what is going on. Since we are using bitwise negation, it is logical to show the numbers in bits, or in other words, print the numbers in binary:

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

printf "%064b\n%064b\n-=-\n", $_, ~ $_ for 1 .. 4;
```

**Output:**

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110
-=-
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101
-=-
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
-=-
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011
-=-
```

Here it is easy to see that the number `1` (represented by `000000....1`) is removed from the end of its bitwise negation, the number `10` (binary for `2`), is removed from the end of its bitwise negation, and so on.

In your case, the use of substitution is irrelevant for the outcome. The important part is that it generates a number.

Answer (score 2):

The substitution doesn't return the changed string, it returns the number of substitutions. `~` is bitwise negation, so what you see is equivalent to `~1`, which is different on 32 and 64 bit Perls.

Compare:

```
say for ~1, unpack "Q", pack "B*", 1 x 64;
```

What you wanted could be achieved by

```
map { s/da//gr } <DATA>;
```

in Perl 5.14 and newer, for older versions, you can't use `/r`, so you have to workaround it:

```
map { s/da//g; $_ } <DATA>;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And please can you clarify that bitwise number, What is meant that.? When i was adding data like `da da`, the bitwise number  could be decreased. what is that.?

Comment: @Hussain: If the number of succesfull substitution increases, you represent it in binary and switch zeroes and ones. What happens?